# How to solve this python math problem? (Likely involves the quadratic formula)

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm quite stumped on how to continue with my current code. Just started learning Python labs in my class (using the Anaconda program, with jupyterlab) and the previous problems were quite simple - yet this one I don't even know how to start with apart from copying the last problem's code as mentioned

Context for the problem :

"Make a graph of the function y = x**2 + x - 11 in range x E [-100, 100] with stepsize of 0.01

Iteratively changing the x- and y-axis limits, find the second root of the function (e.g. when x**2 + x -11 = 0 and x>0)

Finally,

1. Set the x-axis limits so that the root is about in the center of the graph and the total width of the x-axis is 0.30
2. Set the y-axis limits between -1 and 1
3. Read the value of the second root from the graph. Write the value for variable x2 with two decimal accuracy (for example x**2 = 1.23)"

And here is my current code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-100,100,0.01)
y = x**2 + x - 11

# Graphics commands here
x2 = 
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim(-25,25)
plt.ylim(-100,600)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title("y = x**2 + x - 11")
plt.show()
```

I've tried just inserting

```
x1 = (-1 + np.sqrt(1**2 - (4 * 1 *-11)))/(2*1)
x2 = (-1 - np.sqrt(1**2 - (4 * 1 *-11)))/(2*1)

plt.plot([x1, x2], [0, 0],  linestyle = "None", marker = "x")
```

in the middle of the graphics commands.
However I don't know if this is a good start - and I do not understand what the problem wants me to do or how, as this seems too advanced from the previous problems. (I started programming a few weeks ago)

- How do I find the second root of the function?
- How do I set the x-axis limits like in the problem?
- How do I read the value of the second root from the graph?

Comment: "I don't know where to go from here" is too vague a question. What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: Please paste the problem description as text into the question, not a link to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are supposed to read the value of the root from the graph, I don't think you need to bother with the quadratic formula.

Just "zoom in" into the plot by decreasing the x and y limits until you can read the value on the x-axis at which f(x) = 0 with two digit accuracy.
You will need to add an offset to the x limits at some point to keep the root inside the limits and position it like you are supposed to.

Comment: Right.  This is exactly what the problem description says -- read the value from the graph.  You don't need to make the program print the answer.

Answer (score 0):

also, remember the quadratic formula is b^2 +- root(b^2 - 4ac) / 2a

so if you want to plot the points, it should look like

```
x1 = (-1 + np.sqrt(1**2 - (4 * 1 *-11)))/(2*1)
x2 = (-1 - np.sqrt(1**2 - (4 * 1 *-11)))/(2*1)

plt.plot([x1, x2], [0, 0],  linestyle = "None", marker = "x")
```